# Capture the first iteration in a capturing group followed by a quantifier (first character in a sequence)

Tags: python, regex

With this example Regular Expression:

```
([hi]){2,}
```

and this example text:

```
hiiii
```

I'd like the capturing group to contain the **first** character of the sequence (the `h`) - but it will only capture the last one (the `i`) with the current regex. How can I modify it to have it capture the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to isolate it from the rest of the sequence -

```
([hi])[hi]+
```

Here you capture the first `h` or `i`, followed by one or more (total of 2 or more) `h` or `i`s.

---

```
>>> re.findall('([hi])[hi]+', 'hiiii')
['h']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "hiiii"     
print(''.join(re.findall("^\w|\w$", s)))
```

Output:

```
hi
```